# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.io.support.VfsPatternUtils

Tags: spring, wildfly, wildfly-8

As am working on WildFly 8, am getting an error like
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.io.support.VfsPatternUtils

**Log:**

```
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Sample" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Sample: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.io.support.VfsPatternUtils
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.io.support.VfsPatternUtils
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.core.io.support.VfsPatternUtils"}}
```

This is **applicationContext.xml** file Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"`
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rss.master" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
        <property name="username" value="RSS"/>
        <property name="password" value="12345"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource"/>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>hbm/ExRateMaster.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="exRateMasterDao" class="com.rss.master.dao.impl.ExRateMasterDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="exRateMasterBo" class="com.rss.master.bo.impl.ExRateMasterBoImpl">
        <property name="exRateMasterDao" ref="exRateMasterDao"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Check your spring jars... Make sure you aren't mixing different versions...

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?  Where are your dependencies defined (what jar files to include in the application)? Is this a maven project?

Comment: Thanks Mr. M. Deinum

Comment: Thanks Mr John. I resolved the errors. There Was some jar issue , i have not added @appoliance jar and transactional annotation ,now its working